# Trigger Javascript function with conditionals before a block in Gutengerg (WordPress) is saved/published

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to allow the user to set some information in a particular Custom Post Type, what i want to do is to prevent the user to update/publish the post if some of those fields does not meet some requirements.

I was able to accomplished this in the classic editor ( Listen to the event click the "publish/update" button so that it calls me a function which performs the validations I need before the form was saved, if the validations are correct the form was saved correctly. ) but in Gutenberg  this solution does not work

is there a way to trigger a javascript function when the user clicks on "Update/Publish" that will make the validations of those fields and prevent the user to save/publish the block if the requirements are not meet in Gutenberg?

```
$( 'input[name="save"]' ).on( 'click', ( event ) => {
    validateFormQuestionGroups( event );
} );
```

This way I could hear the event click of the button.

Comment: Instead of firing click event on input, try `$( 'form' ).on( 'submit', ( event ) => {
    validateFormQuestionGroups( event );
} );`
It all depends what the `validateFormQuestionGroups` is expecting

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, but as I said, that click event I did it for the classic editor and I need to make the validations in the gutenberg block edition.

Comment: Sorry, I have no knowledge in Gutenberg, I'd start with docs, and github issues for Wordpress Gutenberg.